# I am trying to return Col1 as a value for a list, IF Col2 = NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to return all Col1 values IF the respective Col2 value = NULL
I have thought of IF Col2 = NULL Return Col2 END IF, But I am unsure of how to format this, because when I run it I get errors saying invalid relational operator. Thank you for your time.

SELECT Col1
FROM mytable
WHERE IF NULL Col2 = 0;

---

IF Col2 = NULL
RETURN COL1
ELSE
END IF;

================================================================
EDIT

I apologize for the lack of information/Show of research. First post, So I have been searching google for different IF then statements to deal with NULL values. Everything I have found this far has only showed how to Ignore/convert to 0 so that you can easily work with them. Nothing on how to use them to return values from another col1

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT Col1
FROM mytable
WHERE Col2 IS NULL
```

No `IF` is required. `WHERE` is the SQL `IF` for row selection. This returns only the rows where `Col2` is `null`.

---

If you want to return all the rows, but want to return `Col1` when `Col2` is `null` and `NULL` otherwise, use

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN Col2 IS NULL THEN Col1 ELSE NULL END as myResultColumn
FROM mytable
```

Comment: This was very useful, I am encountering an error when I try to run it, Missing Columns. You're help should be useful enough for me to figure it out from here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

use [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617). it resturns the first non null value

```
SELECT

COALESCE(col1,col2) AS FINAL_COLUMN

FROM [TABLE NAME]
```

Comment: I apologize but I fail to see how this will find all null values in col2?